# Insert data into one column from two other columns of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Table A
FNAME | LNAME
james | Bond
John  | Brit
raje  | van
```

I want to insert first letter from first column with full last name to create a new username column for the table:

```
Table A
USERNAME
jbond
jbrit
rvan
```

If this is not possible, I at least need to update the lastname from lname to newly created username column and to set a default password for all the rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add new column username:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD username varchar(50) 
-- 50 is an example, it should be choosed depending on data
```

then execute this query:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET username = LEFT(fname, 1) + lname
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TableA SET username = SUBSTRING(fname,1,1) + lname
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a computed column (or persisted computed column or even an indexed persisted computed column).

References:

- [Exploring Indexed Persisted Computed
  Columns](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3722696/SqlCredit---Part-12-Exploring-Indexed-Persisted-Computed-Columns.htm)
- [More on Indexed Persisted Computed
  Columns](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3729221/SqlCredit--Part-13-More-on-Indexed-Persisted-Computed-Columns.htm)